# Extract a number from a string after specific string in Oracle SQL

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I would like to extract from this string: `FREQ=DAILY;BYDAY=MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI;BYHOUR=7;BYMINUTE=0;BYSECOND=0`
the number that is after '`BYHOUR=`' string using Oracle pl/sql. 
It can be 1 or 2 character long (0-23)  
It is probably best to use regex regular expression but I was never fluent in creating them.

Can someone help and explain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `REGEXP_SUBSTR`:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, 'BYHOUR=(\d{1,2})')
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, the output though is: 'BYHOUR=12'. Is it possible to get only a number in this statement (using regex) or do I have to use substr() method to get it?

Comment: I think you could change it to this REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, '(\d{1,2})',instr(col,'BYHOUR'))

Comment: @chris See duplicate question's answer

Comment: select  to_number(substr(REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, 'BYHOUR=(\d{1,2})'), 8)) 
from your table